# Assuming you mean 'Optional<LABiometryType>.none'; did you mean 'LABiometryType.none' instead?

Tags: swift, security-framework

It's either this:

[image]

or a warning that not all cases are handled when .none is
removed.
How could I cure this?

Comment: You are using a switch on an optional value. Simplest thing to do is to unwrap it. Could be quickly `switch globaleActiontext?.biometryType ?? LABiometryType.none.`

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
        switch(globalLAcontext?.biometryType) {
            case .touchID:
                titleLabel.text = Localization.string("v1_dotouch_title", "")
                descriptionLabel.text = Localization.string("v1_dotouch_desc","")
                let i = UIImage.image(name: "fingerprint")
                authButton.setImage(i, for: .normal)
                nativeAuthenticationButton.setTitle(Localization.string("v1_dotouch_title", ""), for: .normal)
                showNativeAuthDupButton = true

            case .faceID:
                titleLabel.text = Localization.string("v1_doface_title", "")
                descriptionLabel.text = Localization.string("v1_doface_desc","")
                nativeAuthenticationButton.setTitle(Localization.string("v1_doface_title", ""), for: .normal)
                showNativeAuthDupButton = true

            case .some(.none): fallthrough
            default:
                titleLabel.text = nil
            }
```